# How to read and edit .docx files with PHP?

Tags: php, ms-word, docx

I want to read and edit a DocX document with PHP.

I'm not sure what the right approach is current I'm reading it with `$zip = new ZipArchive`. But this doesn't seem to give any markup or anything.

I want to be able to add for example columns etc to a table. What is the best approach to this? Also I prefer not using libraries.

Edit: Since everyone tells me I should use a library but this is not what I'm looking for, just need to know how to get more info from the docx. I'll parse all the different types etc myself because YES I do want to go without a library

Comment: Libraries.. you need.

Comment: "I prefer not using libraries"  == I prefer re-inventing the wheel and wasting a ton of time.

Comment: Search for "Word document PHP" and you'll find what you need. _Really_, you should use a library.

Comment: You'll probably end up spending weeks/months inventing your own library, if you become successful in the first place.

Comment: _Also I prefer not using libraries_ - have fun with that.

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: Plenty of [possible duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+How+to+read+and+edit+.docx+files+with+PHP%3F) here.

Comment: Why do you not wish to use a library?

Answer (score 4):

Any MS Word document actually is .zip archive.
You can change extension of your .docx file to .zip file and unpack it.

Inside you will see folders:
_rels
docProps
word

The content that you have in the docx file will be here: word\document.xml
So technically you can edit xml file using PHP

Comment: This is what I'm currently using but I'm not getting the style.xml from it, how can I properly read this one out since that decides what type it is if its a header or a table etc